# pythonのPandasで、縦持ちのデータを横持ちにするよい方法を教えてください。

Tags: python, pandas

python初心者です。
いろいろ調べながら進めているのですが、どうしてもすっきりしないので、どなたか教えていただけませんでしょうか？

◆Pandasのデータフレームで、縦持ちのデータを横持ちに変換する方法です。

以下のような縦持ちのデータがあるとします。（csvから読み込み）

```
　　ID　number　item
0　　A　　111　　nn
1　　A　　123　　mm
2　　A　　211　　op
3　　B　　121　　nm
4　　B　　333　　nn
```

これを、次のような横持ちデータにしたいです。
これもデータフレームで出力したいのです。

```
ID　　number　　item　　number　　item　　number　　item
A　　　111　　　　nn　　　123　　　  mm　　　211　　　  op
B　　　211　　　　nm　　　333　　　  nn
```

For文などで地道に実行することはできたのですが、どうも処理速度を考えるとどうかなという気がします。
また、拙いので、ここへの掲載を自粛いたします・・・。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

`groupby`でグループ化し， `apply`でグループ内の要素を結合する関数`f`を適用します． `DataFrame`のまま結合するので同じcolumn名は使えないので，ここでは`number`,`number1`,`number2`,...のように末尾に数字を加えるた新たなcolumnにしています(`rsuffix='{0}'.format(i)`のところ). これで以下のようにDataFrameを作れます．

```
def f(a):    
    a.index = [0 for i in range(len(a))]
    del a['ID']
    out = a[0:1]
    for i in range(1, len(a)):
        out = out.join(a[i:i+1], rsuffix='{0}'.format(i))
    return out

df = pd.DataFrame([['A', 111, 'nn'], ['A', 123, 'mm'], ['A', 211, 'op'],
  ['B', 121, 'nm'], ['B', 333, 'nn']], columns=['ID','number','item'])

df2 = df.groupby(df['ID']).apply(f)
```

出力してみると以下のようになっています．

```
>>>> print(df2)
     item item1 item2  number  number1  number2
ID                                             
A  0   nn    mm    op     111      123    211.0
B  0   nm    nn   NaN     121      333      Nan
```

ただこのままではindexがよけいな0がはいってMultiindexになっているのがうっとおしいので以下のようにすれば，0を消してSingleindexにできます．

```
>>>> df3 = pandas.DataFrame(df2.to_records())
>>>> del df3['level_0']
>>>> print(df3)
 ID item item1 item2  number  number1  number2
0  A   nn    mm    op     111      123    211.0
1  B   nm    nn   NaN     121      333      NaN
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。これでできそうです！
groupbyと関数を組み合わせてみることは、大変勉強になりました。

Answer (score 0):

> 出力はDataframeが理想です。

シンプルと言うには程遠いですが、以下の様になります。

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([
      ['A', 111, 'nn'], ['A', 123, 'mm'], ['A', 211, 'op'],
      ['B', 121, 'nm'], ['B', 333, 'nn'],
    ], columns=['ID','number','item'])

>>> df
  ID  number item
0  A     111   nn
1  A     123   mm
2  A     211   op
3  B     121   nm
4  B     333   nn

>>> df2 = df.groupby('ID')\
      .apply(
        lambda x:
          pd.DataFrame([[list(x.ID)[0]] +
                       list(chain.from_iterable(zip(x.number, x.item)))]))\
      .reset_index(drop=True)

>>> df2.columns = ['ID'] + list(chain.from_iterable(
                    [['number'+str(i+1), 'item'+str(i+1)]
                       for i in range((len(df2.columns)-1)/2)]))

>>> df2
  ID  number1 item1  number2 item2  number3 item3
0  A      111    nn      123    mm      211    op
1  B      121    nm      333    nn      NaN   NaN
```

カラムが足りない部分は `NaN` になります。何か特定の値を入れたい場合は `fillna()` を使うと良いかと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
言葉足らずでしたが、出力はDatafeameが理想です。
確かにこのくらいシンプルだと望ましいです。groupby()はヒントになりそうです。

Comment: 再度、ありがとうございます！最終形もバッチリです。また、私が書いたものよりはシンプルです。そもそも出したい最終形がこうなのは、他のシステムに投入するための並びでしたもので。。

Answer (score 0):

こんなのでもできます。
ID毎にindexを定義できるので、ある程度応用可能です。

```
df["tmpindex"]=df.index
df.tmpindex=df.groupby('ID').tmpindex.rank(ascending=True)
```

成型はこんな感じですかね。

```
df["numberindex"]=df.tmpindex.apply(lambda x: "number{}".format(int(x)))
df["itemindex"]=df.tmpindex.apply(lambda x: "item{}".format(int(x)))
df_pv=pd.concat(
                [
                 df.pivot(index="ID", columns="numberindex",values="number"),
                 df.pivot(index="ID", columns="itemindex",values="item")
                 ],
                axis=1)
df_pv["ID"]=df_pv.index
df_pv.reset_index(drop=True).ix[:,[-1]+list(range(df_pv.shape[1]-1))]
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。 私が少ない知識の中でこうできないかと悶々と考えていた工程に近いです。また、pivotを利用する方法もあるのですね。参考にさせていただきます！